# Snap-installed Krita's icon keeps disappearing from launcher when upgrading

Tags: unity, launcher, snap

I'm using Krita mainly through the snap package and I have its icon pinned to the Unity launcher. My problem is, every time Krita updates through the snap repositories, the launcher icon disappears and I have to run the application (because I can't pin app icons in the dash, unlike Windows 7), and lock its icon to the launcher.

Can this be fixed? I know that Unity is on the way out, but AFAIK Gnome 3 also has an application launcher, so this problem could appear there, too.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed as of `core` 16-2.28.5 (3247) (may also be fixed in 16-2.28.1 (3017)) and `krita` 3.3.1 (27).

At least, when I switch between `krita` 3.3.1 (27) and `krita` 3.2.0-beta.2 (25), the Launcher icon remains locked to the Launcher.

(Please comment if my answer is incorrect)